# How to refresh page when close iframe print dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to refresh main page once i close or print operation from iframe.

Following is my iframe code with added reloading script.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxURL,
            dataType: "text",
            data: { order_id: idsss,shipment:1, shipping_method : oshipping_method,delivery_method:favorite},
        }).done(function(data) {        

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);       
            console.log(obj);       
            $('#myaccount').prepend(obj.scriptname);
            if(obj.filenames != "")
            {
                var splitFiles = obj.filenames.split(',');

                $.each(splitFiles, function( index, value ) {
                    var vale=JSON.stringify(value);
                    var lastword = vale.split("/").pop();
                    console.log(vale);

                    var final =lastword.replace(/\"/g, "");

                     $("<iframe id='printmanifestiframe33'>") // create a new iframe element
                        .hide()
                        .attr("src", "http://localhost/test/pdf/label/"+final) // point the iframe to the page link you want to print
                        .appendTo("body");
                            var frame = document.getElementById('printmanifestiframe33');
                            if (!frame) {
                                alert("Error: Can't find printing frame.");
                                return;
                            }
                            frame = frame.contentWindow;
                            frame.focus();
                            frame.print();                  
                });             
            }
            else
            {
                alert("No order has not been processed.");
            }
            //parent.document.location.reload();
            $('#shipmment_loader').hide();
        });
```

I have used following for refresh main window

```
parent.document.location.reload(); But main window is not refreshing.
```

also i close or print operation from iframe but still not refresh main window.

How could is possible is anything i missing ?

Comment: i think there will be some other solution for that but you can use this as well:
window.location.href === 'http://example.com/sign-in/step-1'

Comment: @MobeenAhmed , I could not found

Comment: have you tried using window.location.href? does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Comment: ok in your code, please copy this and see if it's showing the main url:
alert(parent.parent.window.location);